# Bucle en la hoja de calculo de google

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo, formulas

Estoy trabajando en una hoja de cálculo de Google y necesito hacer, lo que sería a mi entender, un bucle, ya que tengo 2 hojas que se copian una de otra.

Dejo una imagen para que se entienda mejor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que cuando yo escriba algo en el rectángulo rojo de copia 1, se copie en el rectángulo negro de copia 1 y posteriormente realizar la copia 2. Ahora mismo mi problema está en que la fórmula 1 no hace lo que quiero.(No sé si me explico bien)

La fórmula que estoy utilizando es:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Enlace";"Asignacion!A9:AX1000");"select "&Asignacion!T9:AX9&" where Col2='"&B6&"' and Col7='"&C6&"'and Col8='"&D6&"'")
```

Comment: Me parece que sería mejor que en lugar de agregar un lenguaje nuevo a la pregunta, publicaras una nueva pregunta, cómo se debería hacer con las preguntas de seguimiento.

Comment: @Rubén he publicado la nueva pregunta como has sugerido

Comment: Gracias por avisar. Ya te he dejado una respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

[Revisión 8](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/233480/8)

En relación al mensaje de error,

> La referencia de celda está fuera del intervalo. at onEdit(Ordenar:10)

Los índices de getCells las líneas siguientes están mal

```
RangeAsignacion.getCell(2,1).getValue(),
RangeAsignacion.getCell(5,1).getValue(),
```

El error es que se pusieron los índices relativos a a la hoja de cálculo, cuando deberían ser relativos al rango. Por ejemplo, para si el rango es `A2:F2` y se quiere hacer referencia a `A2`, en lugar de usar

```
RangeAsignacion.getCell(2,1).getValue()
```

se debe usar

```
RangeAsignacion.getCell(1,1).getValue()
```

---

[Revisión 3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/233480/3)

Uno de los problemas que tiene tu fórmula es en que el el segundo argumento de QUERY, el de la SQL se incluye

`"select "&Asignacion!T9:AX9`

donde `Asignacion!T9:AX9` es un rango de valores cuando lo que se debería incluir es el nombre de una columna de la forma Col1, Col2, etc.

Otro de los problemas es que el concepto de "bucle" como se muestra en la imagen no se puede llevar a cabo usando fórmulas. Podría resultar confuso el que no se pueda editar una celda del rango `Asignacion!A9:AX1000` que está vacía, y que al editarla agregue "explote". Lo que pasa es que aunque la celda está en vacía, este vacío forma parte de la matriz resultante de la formula que toma los datos de Copia 2.

La alternativa es hacerlo por pasos, usar la formula para importar los datos, copiar y pegar los valores y luego editar. Esto se puede automatizar usando Google Apps Script o bien hacer una solución basada por completo en esto, que no requiera fórmulas.

Comment: Si utilizo Col1, Col2, etc me retorna vacio.

Comment: @IvánMontero Eso puede deberse a la claúsula where

Comment: Es por la claúsula where, pero es una clausula necesaria para que funcione bien, por que la formula 2 sera algo parecido a esto

    `=if(AND(B2=0;E2=0);IMPORTRANGE("Enlace"; "Llista!A6:S1000");if(AND(B2>1;E2=0);query(IMPORTRANGE("Enlace"; "Llista!A6:S1000");"select * where Col6='"&B2&"' order by Col17 DESC,Col18 DESC,Col19 DESC");query (IMPORTRANGE ("Enlace"; "Llista!A6:S1000");"select * where Col6 = '"&B2&"' and Col7 = '"&E2&"' order by Col17 DESC,Col18 DESC,Col19 DESC")))`

modificando done pone A6:S1000 por A6:AX1000

Comment: @IvánMontero Vamos por partes. Primero hay que corregir la cláusula where. Te sugiero crear una hoja de cálculo de demostración, y para tal efecto en una misma pon la "copia 1" y la "copia 2". Ya que logres que funcione, entonces le agregas la lo del IMPORTRANGE.

Comment: No hay manera, no consigo que el where funcione

Comment: Si lo pongo de esta manera el where funciona : `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RLU078ZxW_2yPW_AvW74FLRh8PdCSg0RkoP8i8KbvgU/edit#gid=701630097";"Asignacion!A9:AX1000");"select Col20 where (Col2='"&B6&"' and Col3='"&C6&"' and Col4='"&D6&"') ")`

Comment: Antes de poner la solución, tengo que ver si puedo hacerlo de tal forma que no tenga que poner Col1 , Col2 ... todo el rato

Comment: Si quisiera hacerlo con un script, necesitaria hacer consulta sql como se ve en las formulas que he pasado y por lo que he visto, google apps script no permite sql. He visto que hay una libreria que hace algo parecido [2D Arrays Library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/2d-arrays-library) , no se si tu conoces alguna, creo que intentare con esta.

Answer (score 1):

La solución al problema con el where, era simplemente poner los condicionales entre '()'

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Enlace";"Asignacion!A9:AX1000");"select Col20 where (Col2='"&B6&"' and Col3='"&C6&"' and Col4='"&D6&"') ")
```

Ahora me toca encontrar como hacer que el bucle que estoy haciendo no explote y funcione como yo quiero.

Comment: Los paréntesis no son requeridos por la cláusula WHERE pero sí resultan muy útiles. Quizás te estaba faltando alguna comilla simple o doble. ¿A que te refieres con que "no explote"=

Comment: Basicamente estoy generando un bucle, por lo que es imposible que funcione como yo quiero, fijate en la foto.

Comment: No se puede tener un "bucle" usando fórmulas.

Comment: Si se puede, por que la formula 2 es:

`=if(AND(B2=0;E2=0);IMPORTRANGE("Enlace"; "Llista!A6:AX1000");if(AND(B2>1;E2=0);query(IMPORTRANGE("Enlace"; "Llista!A6:AX1000");"select * where Col6='"&B2&"' order by Col17 DESC,Col18 DESC,Col19 DESC");query (IMPORTRANGE ("Enlace"; "Llista!A6:AX1000");"select * where Col6 = '"&B2&"' and Col7 = '"&E2&"' order by Col17 DESC,Col18 DESC,Col19 DESC")))`

La cual hace que no pueda modificar las casillas que quiero, ademas de tener un relacion ciclica con la otra formula a mi entender

Comment: Basicamente me dice que la matriz no se puede extender por que sobreescribira columnas

Comment: El problema viene del importrange lla que no te permite sobreescribir celdas

Comment: Ahora entiendo a que te refieres con que "explora", si se edita una celda ocupada por los resultados de IMPORTRANGE o cualquier otra función que devuelva un matriz, dejan de mostrarse los resultados de dicha función. Edité mi respuesta.