# Filtrado automático en la hoja de calculo de Google

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Por lo que he visto, el método que intentaba usar en mi otra pregunta [Bucle en la Hoja de cálculo de Google](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/233480/) no es efectivo y como he comentado antes, estoy trabajando con la librería [2D Arrays Library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/2d-arrays-library) Pero no termino de aclararme, este es el código que estoy haciendo:

```
    function onEdit(e){

  var range = e.range;

  var rangeLlista = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Llista").getRange("A6:AX1000");

  var cell = "A9"

  var RangeAsignacion = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Asignacion").getRange("A2:F2");
  var Asignacion = [

    RangeAsignacion.getCell(2,1).getValue(),
    RangeAsignacion.getCell(5,1).getValue()

  ]

  //The var filter should sort the list of the sheet 'Llista' by the cells B2 and E2 that are in sheet 'Asignacion'
  var filter = ArrayLib.filterByText(rangeLlista, -1, Asignacion)

  if(range.getSheet().getName() === 'Asignacion'){

    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell).setValue(filter);

  }

}
```

Uno de los problemas que tengo, es que no entiendo en esta parte del código

```
 var filter = ArrayLib.filterByText(rangeLlista, -1, Asignacion)
```

no sé como poner un Array 2d de Javascript donde pongo 'rangeLLista' que coja todos los datos de la hoja Llista.

Ahora mismo el log me da este error :

La referencia de celda está fuera del intervalo. at onEdit(Ordenar:10)

He solucionado el fallo modificando estas lineas:

```
RangeAsignacion.getCell(1,2).getValue(),
RangeAsignacion.getCell(1,5).getValue()
```

Ahora el problema que tengo es que no me funciona el filtro, solo me escribe 'range' en una celda.

Teniendo en cuenta lo que dice ruben, de momento el código me queda asi, el unico problema es que no filtra:

```
function onEdit(e){

  var range = e.range;
  var colIndex = range.getColumnIndex(); //Same as getColumn()
  var rowIndex = range.getRowIndex(); //Same as getRow()

  //var cell = "A9"

  var rangeLlista = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Llista").getRange("A6:AX1000").getValues();

  var RangeAsignacion = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Asignacion").getRange("A2:F2");
  var Asignacion = [

    RangeAsignacion.getCell(1,2).getValue(),
    RangeAsignacion.getCell(1,5).getValue()

  ]

  //The var filter should sort the list of the sheet 'Llista' by the cells B2 and E2 that are in sheet 'Asignacion'
  var filter = ArrayLib.filterByText(rangeLlista, -1, Asignacion);
  var rows = filter.length;
  var columns = filter[0].length;

  if(range.getSheet().getName() === 'Asignacion'){

    var watchRange1 = {
      top : 2, // start row
      bottom : 2, // end row
      left : 1, // start col
      right : 5, // end col
    };

    if(colIndex >= watchRange1.left && colIndex <= watchRange1.right && rowIndex >= watchRange1.top && rowIndex <= watchRange1.bottom && e.Value != 0){

      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(9,1,rows,columns).setValues(filter);

    };

  };

};
```

Creo que el problema esta en que esta parte retorna un integer y no un string:

```
RangeAsignacion.getCell(1,2).getValue(),
RangeAsignacion.getCell(1,5).getValue()
```

Si modifico esta linea me hace un filtro incompleto:

```
var filter = ArrayLib.filterByText(rangeLlista, -1, Asignacion.toString);
```

Digo que es un filtro incompleto por que no filtra las 2 celdas a la vez, si no que filtra por las que tienen una de las 2 celdas, no se si me esplico.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no he entendido mal, segun lo que dice Ruben, el codigo me quedaria asi:

```
function onEdit(e){

  var range = e.range;
  var colIndex = range.getColumnIndex(); //Same as getColumn()
  var rowIndex = range.getRowIndex(); //Same as getRow()

  //Donde utilizar el filtro
  var rangeLlista = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Llista").getRange("A6:AX1000").getValues();

  //Asignacion de las celdas que tiene que filtrar.
  var RangeAsignacion = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Asignacion").getRange("A2:F2");

  var Asignacion1 = RangeAsignacion.getCell(1,2).getValue().toString();
  var Asignacion2 = RangeAsignacion.getCell(1,5).getValue().toString();

  //Filtros que utilizaremos
  var filter1 = ArrayLib.filterByText(rangeLlista, 6, Asignacion1);
  var filter2 = ArrayLib.filterByText(rangeLlista, 7, Asignacion2);
  var rows = filter2.length;
  var columns = filter2[0].length;

  //Mira si se modifican las celas que nosotros queremos
  if(range.getSheet().getName() === 'Asignacion'){

    var watchRange1 = {
      top : 2, // start row
      bottom : 2, // end row
      left : 1, // start col
      right : 6, // end col
    };

    if(colIndex >= watchRange1.left && colIndex <= watchRange1.right && rowIndex >= watchRange1.top && rowIndex <= watchRange1.bottom && e.Value != 0){

      //Escribe el resultado del filtro
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(9,1,rows,columns).setValues(filter2);

    };

  };

};
```

Estoy provando cosas parecidas, en mi caso el codigo se ejecuta bien pero obtengo el mismo resultado que antes.

Si modifico esto, no me sale el error que digo en el comentario, pero sigue sin funcionar bien el filtro.

```
/Filtros que utilizaremos
  var filter1 = ArrayLib.filterByText(rangeLlista, -1, Asignacion1);
  var filter2 = ArrayLib.filterByText(filter1, -1, Asignacion2);
  var rows = filter2.length;
  var columns = filter2[0].length;
```

Si no estoy entendiendo mal, el codigo me tiene que quedar asi:

```
function onEdit(e){

  var range = e.range;
  var colIndex = range.getColumnIndex(); //Same as getColumn()
  var rowIndex = range.getRowIndex(); //Same as getRow()

  //Donde utilizar el filtro
  var rangeLlista = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Llista").getRange("A6:AX1000").getValues();

  //Asignacion de las celdas que tiene que filtrar.
  var RangeAsignacion = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Asignacion").getRange("A2:F2");

  var Asignacion1 = RangeAsignacion.getCell(1,2).getValue().toString();
  var Asignacion2 = RangeAsignacion.getCell(1,5).getValue().toString();

  var columnIndex1 = 5;
  var columnIndex2 = 6;

  //Filtros que utilizaremos
  var filter1 = ArrayLib.filterByText(rangeLlista, columnIndex1, Asignacion1);
  var filter2 = ArrayLib.filterByText(filter1, columnIndex2, Asignacion2);
  var rows = filter2.length;
  var columns = filter2[0].length;

  //Mira si se modifican las celas que nosotros queremos
  if(range.getSheet().getName() === 'Asignacion'){

    var watchRange1 = {
      top : 2, // start row
      bottom : 2, // end row
      left : 1, // start col
      right : 6, // end col
    };

    if(colIndex >= watchRange1.left && colIndex <= watchRange1.right && rowIndex >= watchRange1.top && rowIndex <= watchRange1.bottom && e.Value != 0){

      //Escribe el resultado del filtro
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(9,1,rows,columns).setValues(filter2);

    };

  };

};
```

Pero me sigue filtrando de forma incorrecta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto un ejemplo de la hoja por si quereis provar cosas:

[Hoja para hacer test](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QNEp9-b-UUyRnFtNmpnbFigJW0O6_tvzUTRloaeG7Bc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Creo que ya entendí a que te refieres en tu comentario a mi respuesta más reciente con que "sigue sin hacerlo bien", que en realidad lo que está pasando no es que no lo haga bien, sino no no devuelve los resultados que estás esperando, porque se están incluyendo `Bomber-conductor GRM` debido a que dicha cadena incluye `Bomber-conductor` pero tu esperas que como no es una coincidencia exacta no se incluyan. No conozco tan a afondo ArrayLib pero quizás no sea la librería adecuada para tu caso.

Comment: Es la unica libreria que he encontrado para esto, no se si conoces alguna.

Comment: Te sugiero realizar una nueva pregunta cuyo título podría ser ¿Cómo filtrar un Array 2D usando dos criterios de coincidencia exacta?, asignes las mismas etiquetas de esta pregunta y además agrega [tag:array]. A esta nueva pregunta agrega un enlace a una copia mejorada de la hoja para hacer test que has hecho, por ejemplo ordena las hojas de acuerdo al flujo, primero pon la hoja con los datos fuente y al final la hoja donde se vaciarían los resultados. En el cuerpo de la pregunta sé muy claro con respecto a los criterios de filtrado y el resultado esperado.

Comment: Incluye también enlaces a esta y la pregunta anterior como parte de tus esfuerzos de buscar/investigar y una breve síntesis de lo abordado en cada una (uso de fórmula, uso de 2D Array Library)

Answer (score 3):

El primer argumento de filterByText debe ser un una Array 2D pero tu código está pasando un objeto Class Range.

Una forma poco elegante pero muy, muy simple de arreglarlo es agregando `getValues()` a

```
var rangeLlista = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Llista").getRange("A6:AX1000");
```

quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
var rangeLlista = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Llista").getRange("A6:AX1000").getValues();
```

Nótese que se agregó `getValues()` antes del `;`. Este método devuelve un Array 2D.

---

A continuación un ejemplo del uso de `ArrayLib.filterByText()` y el vaciado del resultado en una hoja determinada.

```
function myFunction1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var address = 'Hospital2016!A4:P1833' // Referencia de los datos origen
  var data = spreadsheet.getRange(address).getValues();

  // Filtrar datos y obtener número de filas y columnas
  var columnIndex = 6 // OCUPACION [columna G]
  var values = ['HOGAR','ESTUDIANTE']; // Valores a incluir
  var filteredData = ArrayLib.filterByText(data, columnIndex, values);
  var rows = filteredData.length; // número de filas
  var columns = filteredData[0].length; // número de columnas

  // Pasar los datos a la hoja destino
  var destino = 'Hoja 1';
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName(destino).getRange(2,1,rows,columns).setValues(filteredData);
}
```

---

Prueba cambiar

```
RangeAsignacion.getCell(2,1).getValue(),
RangeAsignacion.getCell(5,1).getValue()
```

a

```
RangeAsignacion.getCell(2,1).getValue().toString(),
RangeAsignacion.getCell(5,1).getValue().toString()
```

---

El siguiente ejemplo a mi me funciona sin problemas

```
function test2(){
  var n = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValue().toString();
  Logger.log(n);
}
```

A continuación el transcript de ejecución

```
[19-02-08 13:42:40:252 PST] Starting execution
[19-02-08 13:42:40:258 PST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange() [0 seconds]
[19-02-08 13:42:40:373 PST] Range.getValue() [0.114 seconds]
[19-02-08 13:42:40:386 PST] Logger.log([1, []]) [0 seconds]
[19-02-08 13:42:40:388 PST] Execution succeeded [0.129 seconds total runtime]
```

---

En relación al "filtro incompleto", aplica primero un criterio y luego al resultado de este aplica el segundo, algo así como lo siguiente:

```
function myFunction2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var address = 'Hospital2016!A4:P1833' // Referencia de los datos origen
  var data = spreadsheet.getRange(address).getValues();

  // Filtrar datos y obtener número de filas y columnas
  var columnIndex = 6 // OCUPACION [columna G]
  var values1 = ['HOGAR']; // Valores a incluir
  var filteredData1 = ArrayLib.filterByText(data, columnIndex, values1);


  var values2 = ['ESTUDIANTE']; // Valores a incluir
  var filteredData2 = ArrayLib.filterByText(filteredData1, columnIndex, values2);


  var rows = filteredData2.length; // número de filas
  var columns = filteredData2[0].length; // número de columnas

  // Pasar los datos a la hoja destino
  var destino = 'Hoja 1';
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName(destino).getRange(2,1,rows,columns).setValues(filteredData2);
}
```

---

En

```
var filter2 = ArrayLib.filterByText(rangeLlista, 7, Asignacion2);
```

en lugar de `rangeLlista` debe ser `filter1`

Comment: Gracias por la aportación, el principal problema ahora es que solo me da una celda, cuando tendria que darme varias filas enteras.

Comment: @IvánMontero eso se debe a que tu código sólo tomando una celda, la A9, y además a ella se le está aplicando el método `setValue` el cual sólo asigna un valor. Tendrías que modificar tu script para tomar un rango del tamaño adecuado al resultado de filter y luego usar setValues.

Comment: @IvánMontero Agregué un ejemplo de uso de `ArrayLib.filterByText` , espero te resulte útil.

Comment: Gracias por la aportación, ahora me saca los datos pero no me filtra, he añadido el codigo nuevo a la pregunta por si me puedes ayudar. Creo que el problema es que no paso bien el array de las celdas que tiene que mirar el filtro.

Comment: @IvánMontero Edité mi respuesta.

Comment: getvalue no permite agregarle toString

Comment: @IvánMontero ¿A qué te refieres con que no lo permite? Si ocurre un mensaje de error indica textualmente cuál es. Por cierto, agregué un ejemplo a mi respuesta.

Comment: Nada, añadir toString() si que funciona, el problema que tengo es que filtra las 2 condiciones por separado y no las dos a la vez.

Comment: @Iván No entiendo lo que dices. ¿A qué te refieres que las filtra por separado?

Comment: He añadido una imagen, a ver si se explica mejor

Comment: @IvánMontero He actualizado mi respuesta

Comment: Es una buena idea, pero por lo que estoy provando el codigo no hace nada.

Comment: Provando, me he dado cuenta de que hace lo mismo que el anterior.

Comment: @IvánMontero Actualicé mi respuesta

Comment: Si aplico lo que me dices me sale esto :  "TypeError: No se puede leer la propiedad "length" de undefined.
    at onEdit(Ordenar:20)

Comment: @Iván , perdona, se me pasó cambiar el columnIndex. El 7 cámbialo por el valor que corresponda a la columna del segundo criterio.

Comment: A mi solo me funciona poniendo -1 que es buscar en todas las columnas, pero si miras lo ultimo que he añadido en mi pregunta veras que sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: @IvánMontero He publicado un ejemplo como una nueva respuesta, espero que con este te quede más claro cómo usar ArrayLib para filtrar datos usando dos criterios.

Answer (score 2):

En el siguiente ejemplo se muestra como usar el método filterByText de la librería ArrayLib referida en la pregunta. Con la finalidad facilitar la comprensión de este le simplificado usando una función regular en lugar de usar un activador simple y los criterios se establecen mediante literales en lugar de leer estos de la hoja de cálculo.

Para el ejercicio se utilizaron los datos de Hospital2016.csv descargado de https://datos.gob.mx el verano de 2018. Los criterios son filtrar los datos de `OCUPACIÓN = HOGAR` y `GENERO = FEMENINO`. El resultado se vacía en la hoja llamada `Hoja 1` previamente creada. Para mantener simple le ejemplo, se asume que la hoja destino está vacía.

```
function filtrarDatos2Criterios() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var address = 'Hospital2016!A4:P1833' // Referencia de los datos origen
  var data = spreadsheet.getRange(address).getValues();

  // Filtrar datos usando el primer criterio
  var columnIndex1 = 6 // OCUPACION [columna G]
  var value1 = 'HOGAR'; // Valor a incluir
  var filteredData1 = ArrayLib.filterByText(data, columnIndex1, value1);

  // Filtrar el resultado anterior por el segundo criterio
  var columnIndex2 = 10 // GENERO [columna K]
  var value2 = 'FEMENINO'; // Valor a incluir
  var filteredData2 = ArrayLib.filterByText(filteredData1, columnIndex2, value2);

  // Determinar número de filas y columnas requeridos para desplegar el resultado
  var rows = filteredData2.length; // número de filas
  var columns = filteredData2[0].length; // número de columnas

  // Pasar los datos a la hoja destino
  var target = 'Hoja 1';
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName(target).getRange(2,1,rows,columns).setValues(filteredData2);
}
```

Comment: No se que estoy haciendo mal, pero sigue sin filtrar correctamente.

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste copiar el código de está respuesta y modifica bloque mínimo para que funcione con tus datos? Por ejemplo cambiar los valores de address, value1, columIndex1, value2, columnIndex2 y target.

Comment: He copiado tu codigo y hace algo parecido al mio, sigue sin hacerlo bien.

Comment: @IvánMontero A mi me funciona perfecto.

Comment: @IvánMontero crea un [mcve], es decir, una hoja de cálculo incluyendo una hoja con los datos origen, otra hoja con el resultado esperado, una tercera con para el vaciado de los datos devueltos por el script e incluye tu adaptación de el código de esta respuesta.

Comment: He añadido un enlace a la pregunta