# ¿Cómo filtrar un Array 2D usando dos criterios de coincidencia exacta?

Tags: javascript, array, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Esta es la tercera parte de una pregunta que empezó intentando realizar un filtro en una hoja de cálculo mediante una fórmula:

[Filtrado con fórmula](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/233480/)

Aqui me di cuenta de que lo que queria hacer no se podía mediante las fórmulas de la hoja de cálculo, por lo que decidí intentarlo mediante scripts.

[Filtrado con scripts](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/235022/filtrado-autom%C3%A1tico-en-la-hoja-de-calculo-de-google)

Para realizar dicho filtrado con scripts, intenté utilizar una librería externa llamada [2D Arrays Library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/2d-arrays-library), con la que conseguí filtrar los datos, pero no de la forma en la que yo quería.

Mi intención, es filtrar los datos de un Array 2D en el que pueda utilizar 2 criterios exactos, ya que con la librería sólo he conseguido que me filtre las celdas que contengan dichos criterios.

Para ello, dejo a vuestra disposición una hoja de calculo de test que contiene una lista con los datos a filtrar, una hoja con el filtro actualmente y otra hoja con el resultado esperado ademas de contener el script y la librería que estoy utilizando.

[Hoja de test](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QNEp9-b-UUyRnFtNmpnbFigJW0O6_tvzUTRloaeG7Bc/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dejo la solución <strike>completa</strike> del script:

```
function onEdit(e){

  var range = e.range;
  var colIndex = range.getColumnIndex(); //Same as getColumn()
  var rowIndex = range.getRowIndex(); //Same as getRow()

  //Donde utilizar el filtro
  var rangeLlista = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Llista").getRange("A6:AX500").getValues();

  //Lo que queremos borrar
  var rangeBorrar = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Asignacion");

  //Asignacion de las celdas que tiene que filtrar.
  var RangeAsignacion = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Asignacion").getRange("A2:F2");

  //Los criterios a filtrar
  var Asignacion1 = RangeAsignacion.getCell(1,2).getValue().toString();
  var Asignacion2 = RangeAsignacion.getCell(1,5).getValue().toString();

  //Columna de los criterios a filtrar, la culumna A = 0
  var columnIndex1 = 5;
  var columnIndex2 = 6;

  //Mira si se modifican las celas que nosotros queremos
  if(range.getSheet().getName() === 'Asignacion'){

    var watchRange1 = {
      top : 2, // start row
      bottom : 2, // end row
      left : 1, // start col
      right : 6, // end col
    };

    if(colIndex >= watchRange1.left && colIndex <= watchRange1.right && rowIndex >= watchRange1.top && rowIndex <= watchRange1.bottom && e.Value != 0){

      //Borrado del contenido anterior
      var start = 9;
      var end = rangeBorrar.getMaxRows();

      rangeBorrar.deleteRows(start, end - start);

      //Se realiza el filtrado
      var filteredData = rangeLlista.filter(function (dataRow){

        return dataRow[columnIndex1] === Asignacion1 && dataRow[columnIndex2] === Asignacion2;

      });

      var rows = filteredData.length;
      var columns = filteredData[0].length;
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(9,1,rows,columns).setValues(filteredData);

    };

  };

};
```

Lo único que me gustaría modificar es el método para eliminar las filas, ya que el que utilizo también borra el formato de las celdas.

Comment: "Lo único que me gustaría modificar es el método para eliminar las filas, ya que el que utilizo también borra el formato de las celdas" Resp: En lugar de usar deleteRows, usa [clear(options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearoptions)

Comment: Gracias, no se por que no me deja oredenar lo filtrado por este criterio: `var filteredData = rangeLlista.filter(function (dataRow).sort(19,true){
      
        return dataRow[columnIndex1] === Asignacion1 && dataRow[columnIndex2] === Asignacion2;
      
      });`

Comment: Tu respuesta, ahora aceptada, empieza diciendo que dejas el script completo pero termina diciendo que te falta algo y en tu comentario más reciente dices que falta otra cosa, entonces, el Script no está completo, ¿verdad?. Sobre el último comentario, este es una pregunta de seguimiento, lo apropiado es que lo publiques como una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Cuando la publique lo tenia completo, luego se me ocurrio añadir el sort xd

Comment: Así pasa. Lo ideal sería tu mismo actualizaras la respuesta. En esta ocasión me tomé la libertad de tachar "completo" :)

Answer (score 1):

A continuación se muestra cómo usar el método `filter` de `Array` para filtrar por coincidencia exacta de dos condiciones, se asume que el área correspondiente a los datos filtrados fue vaciada previamente.

```
function filtrarDatos2Criterios() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var address = 'Llista!A6:AX1000' // Referencia de los datos origen
  var data = spreadsheet.getRange(address).getValues();

  // Primer criterio
  var columnIndex1 = 5
  var value1 = 'Bomber-conductor'; // Valor a incluir


  // Segundo criterio
  var columnIndex2 = 6
  var value2 = 'A'; // Valor a incluir

  // Filtrar por coincidencia exacta usando dos criterios
  var filteredData = data.filter(function (dataRow) {
    return dataRow[columnIndex1] === value1 && dataRow[columnIndex2] === value2;
  });


  // Determinar número de filas y columnas requeridos para desplegar el resultado
  var rows = filteredData.length; // número de filas
  var columns = filteredData[0].length; // número de columnas

  // Pasar los datos a la hoja destino
  var target = 'Asignacion';
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName(target).getRange(9,1,rows,columns).setValues(filteredData);  
}
```

Relacionado

- [How to filter an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40849506/1595451)

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, ahora tengo que hacer que se borren los datos antes de filtrar, muchas gracias.